# Calling function on result of operator expression? (mask == instance_id).astype(np.uint8)

Tags: python, numpy, syntax, tuples

I am used to seeing parenthesis instantiate a tuple when they are wrapped around an expression. But in this code it looks like they instead allow a function to be invoked on the result of the operator expression:

```
img = np.random.rand(100,100)
img = img * 100
img = np.round(img)
val = 15
binary_mask = (val == i).astype(np.uint8)
```

Can someone explain the last line of this code? Why is (val == i) not being interpreted as a tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get Python to realise that an expression within parentheses is intended as a tuple with one element, you need to put the `,` after it:

```
binary_mask = (val == i,).astype(np.uint8)
```

Otherwise it's simply interpreted as a parenthesised expression. (Such a string of characters is ambiguous, so Python naturally parses it the way it's most commonly intended, as well as giving you an explicit way to indicated the other.)

To support the above with a quote from the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

```
A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1 items: the 
syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty tuples are 
constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with one item is 
constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not sufficient to enclose 
a single value in parentheses). Ugly, but effective.
```